# 403 Forbidden error while accessing twitter api

Tags: python, twitter, oauth

I am trying to access twitter api and to do that I am trying to get a bearer key as they mentioned in twitter api documentation

here is what I wrote so far

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import oauth2 as oauth
import json
import base64
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import Request
from urllib.request import urlopen


def main():
    try:
        consumer_key = b'b1...H49'
        consumer_secret = b'0w...5H'
        base64_consumer_key_secret = base64.b64encode(consumer_key + b':' + consumer_secret)

        #step 2 : obtain bearer token
        print(base64_consumer_key_secret)
        request = Request('https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token',b'grant_type=client_credentials')
        request.add_header('Authorization',b'Basic' + base64_consumer_key_secret)
        request.add_header('Content-Type', b'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8')
        request.add_header('User-Agent',b'Mozilla/5.0')
        response = urlopen(request)
   except Exception as e:
          print('unable to open url', e)
  else:
       data = json.load(response)
       if data['token_type'] != 'bearer':
          throw('Bad token_type: ' + data['token_type'])
       access_token = data['access_token']
       print ('access_token is ' + access_token)

 if __name__ == "__main__": 
      main()
```

I am getting a error message as 403 forbidden . I understand that this error code means I framed the request in a right way but I do not have a sufficient permission. I have created a test app with twitter and got consumer key and secret as mentioned. Is there something am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Do not post your consumer keys and secret publicly!

Comment: sorry my bad!! Any suggestion about the error message?

Comment: most likely permission issues. double check them.